# CRM 2016 - Ribbon Workbench - Error when Publish Solution: The User ID is Invalid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am having this error when using RibbonWorkbench (latest version). When I click Publish, the progress dialog show this step: "Importing solution", then after few minutes, it throws this error:

```
Error when publishing Solution 
RBW:3.1.177.1,CRM:8.2.0.749 
Import Failed : Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException [[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.osf, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The user Id(s) [f3acea0e-57f3-4dcf-835a-48603998e79d] is invalid.Detail: 
<osf xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"> 
<ActivityId>53161f82-3291-4a32-a8ff-306cd84436e8</ActivityId> 
<ErrorCode>-2147214049</ErrorCode> 
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1=""> 
<key> 
<d2p1:key>0</d2p1:key> 
<d2p1:value i:type="d4p1:string">f3acea0e-57f3-4dcf-835a-48603998e79d</d2p1:value> 
</key> 
</ErrorDetails> 
<Message>The user Id(s) [f3acea0e-57f3-4dcf-835a-48603998e79d] is invalid.</Message> 
<Timestamp>2017-11-21T07:15:18.3500676Z</Timestamp> 
<ExceptionSource i:nil="true" /> 
<InnerFault i:nil="true" /> 
<OriginalException i:nil="true" /> 
<TraceText i:nil="true" /> 
</osf>
Stack Trace: 
Error: 
at Function.ClientUI.ViewModel.EditCommandBarsVM.queryImport (:19555:1448) 
at :19556:38
```

I faced this error when publishing any solution/entity. I created a new entity a try to Publish it in RibbonWorkbench, it always show the same error.

***The user Id(s) [f3acea0e-57f3-4dcf-835a-48603998e79d] is invalid.***
The user GUID is SYSTEM user in our environment.

Could you please show me where should I check this problem? I have googled this error without any result

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just wanna double check, this user is added into CRM, right?

Comment: Is default `Publish/Publish All Customization` working ??

Comment: Yes, the user GUID in the Error Message is the built-in "SYSTEM" user of CRM (not my user and this SYSTEM user is locked user, no one can edit the record). I am using my user to Publish the solution in Ribbon workbench (has Admin role). Publish/Publish All of solution in CRM (not Publish button in Ribbon) works fine. Thanks

Comment: To clarify,I have tried these step to identity the issue:
1/Create new solution
2/Create new entity without and customization, add to above solution
3/Open Solution in Ribbon Workbench 2016
4/Then without adding any new Button, I click the "Publish" button
-->   Ribbon Workbench 2016 throw above Error